# body params properties name change in signed APK

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I created an android application which I use retrofit as REST client.

when i install the app on a phone, the requests are sent without any problem, but when i'm building a signed APK, i don't know why the properties name change when sending the request

I have a class which contains a "**phone**" field, then the request body must be

```
{
    "phone": "123456"
}
```

but in the log, I see that the body turns into

```
{
    "a": "123456"
}
```

the problem occurs only in signed APK,

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Fix disable minifyEnabled to false.

```
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ...
    }
```

> OR

If you dont want your class members to be obfuscated then use SerializedName annotation provided by Gson. For example:

```
public class ClassNameHere
{
   @SerializedName("phone")
   public String phone;
     ...

}
```

Moreover, make sure you do add proper proguard configuration for Gson library too. For example:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with
#fields. Proguard removes such information by default, so configure it to keep
#all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.mypackage.ClassNameHere.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
```

For more info read proguard rules

Comment: thank you for your answer :) do I have to use annotations on all attributes? is there any other method i can use? because I have a lot of queries with body params

Comment: @Ghaylen i just updated answer for quick fix please check

Comment: Glad to help 

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an R8 / proguard issue.

For debug builds usually it is disabled, so no optimalization, obfuscation takes place, but for release apks, it is usually turned on (as it should!).

```
// this line in build.gradle
minifyEnabled true
```

This doesn't depend on retrofit, but your json converter, GSON or Moshi or anything else. You need to either "keep" (by adjusting proguard rules) your model classes or annotate them properly so the converter works as expected.

For moshi the usual way is to generate the model's json converter via annotation processor

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) 
class PhoneModel(@Json(name = "phone") val phoneField: String)
```

But check out your converter's readme page on proguard / R8